# Python - 0**0 == 1?

Tags: python, math, pow

I was playing around with `**` operator, and noticed that:

```
0**0 == 1
```

And

```
pow(0, 0) == 1
```

And even `math`:

```
math.pow(0, 0) == 1
```

And **Google**! (search for `0**0`)

Why is it so? As far as I know 0**0 is undefined

Comment: In case you googled it, you could have seen the link just below calculator. Read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are mistaken.  It works as it should.

`n/0` is undefined.  `0**0` however is `1` because any number raised to the power of `0` is `1`.

Here are some references:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221031621/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.number.to.0power.html)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

Comment: Strange. At school I was told that 0**0 is invalid

Comment: @Vik2015 - Huh.  Well, all I can say is that your teacher is wrong.  Maybe you should challenge them and say that SO sent you? ;)

Comment: `0/0` is invalid, but `0**0` is not :)

Comment: @iCodez, maybe I will :). But the point is, in the book it is explained that `x**0 = (x**3)/(x**3)`. If we place `0` instead of `x` we get: `0**0 = (0**3)/(0**3)`, so we get ZeroDivision!

Comment: @Vik2015: That's not a convincing argument.  Consider that equally, `x**2 = (x**5) / (x**3)`.  So substituting `0` for `x`, `0**2 = (0**5) / (0**3)`.  So `0**2` should be undefined, too!

Comment: The book presents its "proof" incorrectly. `(x**3)/(x**3)` is really `(x**3)×(x**-3)`; no division takes place.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, msw. Huh, you guys are right. Gonna ask my teacher tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Anything to the power 0, by definition, is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the math rules. Everything in a 0-th power is 1.